# ftp_ nlist limit

Tags: php, linux, ftp, debian

I'm using ftp_nlist -function like this:

```
    $list = @ftp_nlist($conn, $dir);
```

But this only works if in directory has less than 50000 files. FTP server i'm using is vsftpd/debian. Is there any option to change this 50000 items limit? Php/apache/kernel .conf or something?

Comment: Where did you get that piece of information that ftp_nlist() only supports 50.000 files ?

Comment: Just by testing. I have now about 52000 files in directory and ftp_nlist is not working. But if I remove some files from directory everything works nice.

Comment: Have you tried to boost max_execution_time ?

Comment: No but I don't think that its execution time problem. This ftp_nlist -function executes quite fast (2-3 sec) when it works (under 50000 files).